# Xcode 5: Pre-action scripts are executed during project cleaning

Tags: ios, xcode, build

I have added custom script as pre-action for Build phase in my scheme (I need to perform several changes (including Info.plist manipulations) before build actually starts - thus I can't use build phase scripts because they run after Info.plist is copied to the product). Everything works fine, except the fact that this script is also executed when I clean my project. And I don't need it.

I checked environment and possible params passed to the script in different cases, but they are equal in both build and clean scenarios.

Is there any way to disable script execution during clean-up? Or may be it is possible to check somehow in the script if it was started during clean-up or during build.

I'm using Xcode 5.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the value of $ACTION environment variable? It should have "build" value for build and "clean" for clean-up.

Comment: Xcode 7.3: the $ACTION ev variable doesn't have any value when I clean the project inside Xcode. It has correct values when I clean project from command line with xcodebuild command. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the differences in the output of `env` between `clean` and `build` actions shows only two differences:

`RUN_CLANG_STATIC_ANALYZER=NO` for build, and `YES` for clean, and
`CLANG_STATIC_ANALYZER_MODE=shallow` for build and `deep` for clean

I'm not sure if that's enough to reliably differentiate a clean from a build, and may vary depending on other build settings, but it may be better than nothing?

FWIW, Xcode/shell mangles newlines when doing a naive `echo $(env) > /tmp/env.log`.  The pre-action [fragment](https://superuser.com/a/284226/456458) I used to generate usable `diff`able output is:

```
: > /tmp/env.log # Truncate the logfile
ENV=$(env)
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line" >> /tmp/env.log
done <<< "$ENV"
```

(BTW, 8 years after the question was asked, so this applies to Xcode 12.5.1.  YMMV!)